# Can't view Firebase data in tableview Swift 4

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

Im having a issue where I can't view anything that I write to my Firebase database in my table view. I previously had some working code to view my database entries but had to revise how I write data to the database so I can save the unique ID generated by childByAutoID(), so I may delete an entry later. Here's my code:

Heres how I write to Firebase:

```
ref = Database.database().reference() //  sets the variable "ref" to connect to our Firebase database
 let key = ref?.child("task").childByAutoId().key
            let post = ["uid": key,       // Gets auto generated ID for database entry
                        "title": input.text,                    // Saves the title field to Firebase
                        "description": inputField.text]         // Saves the description field to Firebase
            ref?.child("task").child(key!).setValue(post)      // Saves the task for Firebase, ties each post with a unique ID

            var arr : [(String, String)] = [];
            for (key, value) in post {
                arr.append((key, value!));
```

Heres my TableViewController:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return (arr.count)
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: 
UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    let (key, value) = arr[indexPath.row]; //read element for the desired cell
    cell.textLabel?.text = key
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = value
    return (cell)
}        
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {//change "viewDidLoad()" back to "viewDidAppear()"
    ref = Database.database().reference()                  // sets the variable "ref" to connect to our Firebase database

    list.removeAll()    // Deletes all older data, so only data thats on the Firebase Database will be added to the "list" array
    desc.removeAll()    // Deletes all older data, so only data thats on the Firebase Database will be added to the "desc" array

    handle = ref?.child("task").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

if let item = snapshot.value as? String
        {
            arr.append(item)
            list.append(item)
            //desc.removeAll()
            self.myTableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Firebase` returns the items in form of `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` or `NSString`. ([Refer here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_data_once))
Since your `post` object is `NSDictionary`, parse the snapshot value as a Array of Dictionary. try the following:

```
if let itemArray = snapshot.value as? [[String : Any]] {

  // Looping logic on 'itemArray' to get your sent dictionaries on the firebase 
  // After looping logic add Ui logic out of loop
}
```

Comment: I dont understand by what you mean by "bind it the same way"? I've tried a few things but I'm still having trouble.